# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "download.gif": no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I was just learning python gui and this error showed up.
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "download.gif": no such file or directory
this the code

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

icon = PhotoImage(file= 'download.gif')
window.iconphoto(True , icon)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the gif in the same folder of the python script?

Comment: More importantly, what is the current working directory when you run the script?

Comment: To elaborate what @martineau says: [Get directory of current Python script - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-directory-of-current-python-script/ "Get directory of current Python script - GeeksforGeeks")

Answer (score 0):

You can access your file by specifying the file path.

```
like "/cd:/yourp-path/../../images/dowload.gif"
```

Comment: but why can't relative path work?